# Exponential potential in physics

Tags: schroedinger-equation, potential

Given the differential equation

$$ -\hbar^{2}D^{2}y(x)+ae^{bx}y(x)=E_{n}y(x) $$

here $ D=d/dx $ is the derivative,

are there examples in physics where this potential appears ?? I know how to solve it but I do not know pratical examples where the exponential potential appears.

the solution is given by

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-y%27%27%28x%29%2Baexp%28bx%29y%28x%29%3Dcy%28x%29

Comment: You are *completely* comfortable with the [Morse potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_potential), no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1D Quantum scattering from $V(x) = e^x$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/349207/1d-quantum-scattering-from-vx-ex)

Comment: It's the space part of the equation for the massive Klein-Gordon field in Rindler coordinates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/418926/solving-the-kg-equation-in-rindler-coordinates/419121#419121