# Solving the KG equation in Rindler coordinates

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Let us consider a massive Klein-Gordon scalar field $\phi$ satisfying $$(\Box+m^2)\phi=0$$

I want to solve this in Rindler coordinates, choosing $\phi$ to be positive frequency with respect to the generator of boosts $\partial_\eta$. The idea is to find a set of basis modes to quantize the field in the Rindler frame.

Now, we have the $\Box$ operator given by

$$\Box\phi=e^{-2a\xi}(-\partial_\eta^2+\partial_\xi^2)\phi$$

Thus the equation becomes

$$e^{-2a\xi}(-\partial_\eta^2\phi+\partial_\xi^2\phi)=-m^2\phi$$

Imposing that $\partial_\eta \phi=-i\omega \phi$ we have $\phi(\eta,\xi)=A(\xi)e^{-i\omega \eta}$ and hence after some manipulation we get the equation for $A$

$$A''(\xi)+\omega^2A(\xi)+m^2 e^{2a\xi}A(\xi)=0.$$

I now set $u(\xi)=\frac{m}{a}e^{a\xi}$. Perfoming the change of variables and dividing through by $a^2$ gives

$$u^2 \dfrac{d^2A}{du^2}+u\dfrac{dA}{du}+\frac{\omega^2}{a^2}A+u^2A=0.$$

Defining $\alpha = -i\omega/a$ we then have

$$u^2 \dfrac{d^2A}{du^2}+u\dfrac{dA}{du}+(u^2-\alpha^2)A=0.$$

This is Bessel's equation and its solution is

$$A(u)=c_1 J_\alpha (u)+c_2 Y_\alpha(u).$$

Using $u = u(\xi)$ gives $A(\xi)$ and solves the problem.

The issue is, usually boundary conditions allow us to eliminate $c_1$ or $c_2$. If we want a solution regular at $u=0$ we would have $c_2 =0$ for instance.

But here I'm failing to see this. For instance, $u=0$ corresponds to $\xi\to -\infty$. I don't see why impose regularity there.

How can we proceed? We must leave both $c_1,c_2$, or is there some further manipulation we can do?

**Edit**: Rindler coordinates are defined by

$$t=\dfrac{1}{a}e^{a\xi}\sinh(a\eta),\quad x=\dfrac{1}{a}e^{a\xi}\cosh(a\eta)$$

Comment: Could you add the definition of the Rindler coordinates ? I am not familiar with their definition.

Comment: I've added the definition of the Rindler coordinates as presented in Sean Carroll's Spacetime and Geometry GR textbook.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll do it in 2d as the extra dimensions are trivial.

If $x$, $t$ are Minkowski coordintes and we we set
$$
t= e^{\xi} \sinh \tau\nonumber\\
x= e^{\xi} \cosh \tau\nonumber
$$
then $-\infty<\xi< \infty$, $-\infty<\tau < \infty$ covers the Rindler wedge. 
In these coordinates the  metric $ds^2= dx^2-dt^2$ becomes
$$
ds^2= e^{2\xi}(d\xi^2-d\tau^2).
$$
The usual Rindler coordinate  sets $r= e^{\xi}$ so that
$$
ds^2 = dr^2-r^2 d\tau^2.
$$

For the KG equation the $\xi$, $\tau$ coordinates are nicer as
$$
(-\nabla^2+m^2)\psi(x)=0
$$
becomes (after multiplication by $e^{2\xi}$)
$$
\left(-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \tau^2}+m^2 e^{2\xi}\right)\psi(\xi,\tau)=0.
$$

The real eigenfunctions of the equation
$$
\left(-\frac{d^2}{d\xi^2}+m^2 e^{2\xi}\right) \psi_\nu(\xi)=\nu^2 \psi_\nu(\xi)
$$
are
$$
\psi_\nu(\xi)=\left( \frac{2\nu \sinh  \nu \pi}{\pi^2}\right)^{1/2} K_{i\nu}(m e^{\xi}), \quad 0<\nu<\infty
$$
where $K_{i\nu}(x)$ is the Bessel K function of purely imaginary order.

The eigenfunctions  have been normalized to  obey
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_\mu(\xi)\psi_\nu(\xi)\, d\xi = \delta(\nu-\mu),
$$ 
and are the ingredients of the Kontorovich–Lebedev transform (There is Wikipedia article on this) which makes it clear that this set of solutions  is both orthogonal and complete.

Thus the KG equation has solutions
$$
\psi_\nu(\xi,\tau) =e^{-i\nu \tau}\psi_\nu(\xi).
$$ 
There is no need to worry about boundary conditions as, in  the $\xi$, $\tau$ coordinates, we are in the Weyl limit-point case.

Here are a few more details taken from my notes:

Consider the Bessel function
$$
{\rm K}_{i\nu}(x)= \int_0^\infty e^{-x\cosh u}\cos \nu u\, du\nonumber\\
=\frac 12 \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{i\nu} \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-t-\frac{x^2}{4t}\right) t^{-i\nu -1}\,dt.\nonumber
$$
of purely imaginary order. The function  ${\rm K}_{i\nu}(x)$ is real for $x\in (0,\infty)$, and ${\rm K}_{i\nu}(x)={\rm K}_{-i\nu}(x)$.
For small $x$
$$
{\rm K}_{i\nu}(x)\sim \frac{i\pi}{2\sinh \pi \nu}\left\{ \frac{(x/2)^{i\nu}}{\Gamma(1+i\nu)}- \frac{(x/2)^{-i\nu}}{\Gamma(1-i\nu)}\right\}\nonumber\\
= \sqrt\frac{\pi}{\nu \sinh \pi \nu} \left\{ e^{i\alpha} (x/2)^{i\nu} + e^{-i\alpha} (x/2)^{-i\nu}\right\}\nonumber
$$
for some real $\alpha$. We have used, at the last step,
$$
\Gamma(1+i\nu)\Gamma(1-i\nu)= \frac{\pi \nu}{\sinh \pi \nu}.
$$

These functions  therefore satisfy the orthogonality property
$$
\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x} {\rm K}_{i\mu}(mx){\rm K}_{i\nu}(mx)= \frac{\delta(\mu-\nu)}{2\nu \sinh \nu \pi},
$$
and a completeness condition
$$
\frac{1}{\pi^2} \int_0^\infty 2\nu\sinh \nu\pi \,{\rm K}_{i\nu}(x){\rm K}_{i\nu}(x')\,d\nu= x \delta(x-x').
$$
and provide the  *Kontorovich-Lebedev*  transform pair
$$
\tilde f(\nu)\equiv K[f](\nu)= \int_0^\infty {\rm K}_{i\nu}(x) f(x)\,dx,\nonumber\\
f(x)= \frac{1}{\pi^2 x} \int_0^\infty 2\nu \sinh \nu\pi\, {\rm K}_{i\nu}(x) \tilde f(\nu)\,d\nu.\nonumber
$$

There is also a Mehler-type convergent 
$$
\frac{1}{\pi^2} \int_0^\infty 2\nu\sinh \nu(\pi-\epsilon)  {\rm K}_{i\nu}(x){\rm K}_{i\nu}(y)\,d\nu= \frac{xy}{\pi}  \sin\epsilon  \frac{{\rm K}_1(\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2xy \cos\epsilon})}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2xy \cos\epsilon}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still, the whole problem I have is exactly in showing that the solution to that eigenvalue problem is given by the modified Bessel function. First, one needs to show that that equation is actually the modified Bessel equation. I believe my change of variables is the correct one, but I got Bessel's equation instead of the modified one. Second, even after you get the equation you have two linearly independent solution (first and second kinds), and here we are picking just the modified Bessel function of second kind, dropping the other. Why is that anyway?

Comment: You probably have to select $c_1$ and $c_2$ so that the general solution reduces to the right form in a certain asymptotic limit.  For example, for large $\xi$, the observer's acceleration goes to zero and we should expect the solution to reduce to a plane wave.  The large-argument limit of the Bessel functions are sinusoids, and you can probably set either $c_1$ or $c_2$ to zero to pick out the positive frequency solution.  I haven't worked this out...just a thought that parallels the development of inflationary perturbations.

Comment: @user1620696  I think the issue of "modified" rather than usual Bessel comes from your haveing the wrong sign for $m^2$. In the third eq in your post, and setting $a=0$ your eq leads to   $\omega^2 =k^2 -m^2$.  You should have $\omega^2= k^2+m^2$. Also the K Macdonald function has the correct wavelike solutions at  both $\pm \infty$.

Comment: @user1620696 I meant that $K_{i\nu} $ function has the correct wavelike behaviour at $\xi=-\infty$ and exponential decay at $\xi=+\infty$. The latter because the massive particle cannot escape, and eventually  falls into the horizon.

Comment: @mikestone thanks for warning me. I think the problem is that I mixed the two types of signatures $(-,+,+,+)$ and $(+,-,-,-)$. Correcting this yields the right modified Bessel equation. Now, I think your point of view that for large $\xi$ the solution should reduce to a plane wave is a good one.

Comment: @user1620696 I was mistaken about the plane wave at large distaance. The wavefunction decays out there because the particle cannot escape to infinity and always falls through the Rindler horizon.  At short distance, however the solution look like a standing wave mad of ingoing and outgoing plane waves