# Problem in solving Schrodinger equation of an exponential potential analytically

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, schroedinger-equation

So I am having difficulty in solving the 1D TDSE for the potential

$$V(x)=C(e^{-2x/a} - e^{-x/a})$$

It models a diatomic molecule, I tried to do a change of variables to $y = k e^{-x/a}$ and then look at the asymptotic behavior of the DE we get.

Could someone point me in the right direction how to solve this please?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72945/2451

Answer (score 1):

A problem like this is solved in the  Landau & Livshitz quantum mechanics (Problem 4 in chapter 23, *Linear oscillator*, in my Russian edition). These cite *Ph. Morse, 1929*- so, if you are interested to go to the sources or get more information, then look for [Morse potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_potential).

Wikipedia link above actually contains the reference to the original More's aryicle:
[Morse, P. M. (1929). "Diatomic molecules according to the wave mechanics. II. Vibrational levels". Phys. Rev. 34. pp. 57–64](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.34.57).

Finally, I would not be surprized, if the problem is also treate in [Morse and Feshbach](https://www.amazon.fr/Methods-theoretical-physics-Philip-Feshbach/dp/B0017WJSN0).